# Bitwise operators (x86 Assembly): Where does the rest of the binary data go when shifting it?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I know that when I execute the following line of Assembly x86 code:

```
shrl $31, %eax
```

If EAX has the following 32-bit data:

```
10000010000000000000000000000000
```

Then executing the command `shrl $31, %eax` results in:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

However, where do the other bits (`000001`) go? Where exactly are they located in memory?

Comment: Huh? That's not what happens. `mov` overwrites the destination and `31` is not `1`. Irrespective of what was previously in `eax` it will become `00000000 00000000 00000000 00011111`

Comment: @Jester Updated my code, it was a typo :D.

Comment: Well fix the other one then too :D But yeah, bits shifted out are gone except for the last one that goes into the carry.

Comment: If you want those bits that got "shifted out", perhaps you are interested in [SHRD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/shrd)

Comment: Entropy. They go to entropy. Theoretically, computer operations can be made to use arbitrarily little energy as long as they are nondestructive. Once information is lost (for example, when it is necessary to reset a register to zero), entropy must be increased.

Comment: The hardware bits don't move, they are quite stationary; they simply change value.  That there is some logical notion of bits and their values is a human interpretation, not manifest in hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those bits are discarded because that's what shifting them out means, and that's what you asked the machine to do.  Just like in C, `u32_var >>= 31;` doesn't magically update some other location with the bits shifted out.

If you wanted them to go somewhere, use [`shrd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/shrd) (2-register shift, although it only updates one of the registers.  To do a `uint64_t` shift like `>>= 31` on a pair of 32-bit registers (EDX:EAX), you need `shrd $31, %edx, %eax` / `shr $31, %eax`)

There's zero reason that shifting a register would result in a store to memory, that would be an insane design.  Even shifting them into some temporary register would be weird, and would require a wider barrel shifter to implement shifts efficiently.  (Which x86 needs for `shrd`, but other ISAs with shift instructions don't always have double-precision shifts.  Of course, 8086 didn't have 386 shrd, but it also didn't have a barrel shifter: each shift count cost an extra cycle.)

---

x86 instruction are not all reversible. Many (like shifts by more than 1) discard some information.  You could just as easily ask where the bits went after `sub %eax, %eax` or `xor %eax, %eax` zeros the register, or after `or $-1, %eax` set it to all-ones.  Some like `not`, `neg`, or `xor` (with different registers) are reversible by repeating, or `add` / `sub` are reversible by doing the other one.  (Still destroying the old FLAGS, though.)

**Shifts leave the last bit shifted out in CF**, so they always destroy the old contents of CF (unless the shift count is 0, then FLAGS are unmodified.  x86 is so CISC it hurts.  That's why variable-count shifts cost 3 uops on Intel CPUs. >.<)

Shifts by 1 leave the all the original bits of the input register around, and can be undone by a rotate-through-carry (`rcl` or `rcr`) in the other direction.

---

related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing - information theory and thermodynamics.  Specifically the [Logical reversibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing#Logical_reversibility) section discusses how you might compute things without discarding any bits.

Of course, our current technology for digital logic in silicon uses vastly more power than the information-theoretical minimums even for the amount of information they destroy during computation (by *many* orders of magnitude).  So destroying information or not with your choice of instructions is completely irrelevant to power consumption.